# CSS Hover Menu Item

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a fixed navigation on the bottom of my website. The trouble I am having is that the hover effect (background) slides up before I even have my mouse over the text. At the moment the background slides up when my mouse enters the .item-container. Basically I need to make the hover effect take place ONLY when my mouse is over the text and not the outside divs.

I have a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/dLz8fL80/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="item-container">
                    <div class="item-top">The Song</div>
                    <div class="item-bottom-song-content">The Song</div>
                    <div class="item-bottom-song">Have a Listen</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Not really possible since you are trying to affect the parent element by hovering a child. You might want to re-think.

Comment: Well, this question is asked many times before, and the short typical answer is: It cannot be done by pure CSS. It's in the name: Cascading Style Sheets only supports styling in cascading direction, not up. It's the issue that @Paulie_D stated above. It IS POSSIBLE using JQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: If you want i can help you but using JavaScript/JQuery, it would be much easier.

Comment: in the future, the CSS4 `:has()` pseudo selector will probably help. We're not there yet though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this in your css:

```
.item-container {
    top: 150px;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.item-container:hover {
    height: 225px;
    line-height: 300px;
    top: -210px;
}
```

Your problem was that you have set initial height of you container to `225px` and whenever you hover that area it pops out the item content, i.e. when hover above bottom item text the content pops out.

What you need to change is the height of your `.item-container`. You have to set it like `30px` when they are not hovered, and when you hover some of them, then you want it to show it's content with it's original height `225px`.

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tzuer2b/2/)

Comment: Thanks. This does work however it seems to be jittery if you know what I mean. Can the text be at the same level when I hover, too? Cheers!

Comment: Yes, sure it can. I have updated the fiddle. I was in a hurry and I guess I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: @1|13v Question: For iPad I won't to remove the hover states and just have the links. What classes would I need to remove?

Comment: read something about media queries  here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
you gonna have to use different css rules for different resolutions.
Try with this `.item-container:hover {
 top: 0;
}` inside media query with your desiraed resolution

Comment: @1|12v I understand how to use CSS media queries I just need some help removing the correct classes to get this effect. So I just need to remove the hover image states and instead just have the links as they are now. When the user hovers them it would change from white to purple.

Answer (score 0):

though few nesting/structural level  issues are there do correct them but got your code working from what have you  provided see if it helps.

```js
$('.item-top').find('span').hover(function(e) {


  $(this).parents('.item-container').css("top", "-225px");

  e.stopPropagation();


});

$('.item-container').mouseleave(function() {

  $(this).css("top", "0px");


});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}
/*
* Addresses `font-family` inconsistency between `textarea` and other form
* elements.
*/

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
/*
* Addresses margins handled incorrectly in IE 6/7.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000e22;
}
dl,
menu,
ol,
ul {
  margin: 1em 0
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 40px
}
/*
* Addresses paddings set differently in IE 6/7.
*/

menu,
ol,
ul {
  padding: 0
}
nav ul,
nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 225px;
  z-index: 999999;
}
nav ul {
  height: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul li {
  width: 16.65%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 225px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}
nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'DINWeb-CondBold';
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.item-container {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 225px;
  line-height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.item-top,
.item-bottom {
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
}
.item-bottom-song-content {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.item-bottom-project-content {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #51338f;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.item-bottom-behind-content {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #a32d8f;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.item-bottom-batten-content {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #30abdf;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.item-bottom-about-content {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ea158c;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.item-bottom-sharing-content {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.item-top {
  color: #ffffff;
  dispay: none
}
.item-bottom-song {
  background: #00ff00 url("http://www.ambafrance-nz.org/IMG/jpg/DSCF2642.jpg?3829/99c4f531ec5ee485e00f5ac22e2466558b19c634") no-repeat center center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.item-bottom-project {
  background: #00ff00 url("http://www.ambafrance-nz.org/IMG/jpg/DSCF2642.jpg?3829/99c4f531ec5ee485e00f5ac22e2466558b19c634") no-repeat center center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.item-bottom-behind {
  background: #00ff00 url("http://www.ambafrance-nz.org/IMG/jpg/DSCF2642.jpg?3829/99c4f531ec5ee485e00f5ac22e2466558b19c634") no-repeat center center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.item-bottom-batten {
  background: #00ff00 url("http://www.ambafrance-nz.org/IMG/jpg/DSCF2642.jpg?3829/99c4f531ec5ee485e00f5ac22e2466558b19c634") no-repeat center center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.item-bottom-about {
  background: #00ff00 url("http://www.ambafrance-nz.org/IMG/jpg/DSCF2642.jpg?3829/99c4f531ec5ee485e00f5ac22e2466558b19c634") no-repeat center center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.item-bottom-sharing {
  background: #fff url("http://www.ambafrance-nz.org/IMG/jpg/DSCF2642.jpg?3829/99c4f531ec5ee485e00f5ac22e2466558b19c634") no-repeat center center;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="item-container">

          <div class="item-top"><span>The Song<span></div>
          <div class="item-bottom-song-content">The Song</div>
        <div class="item-bottom-song">Have a Listen</div>
        
      </div>
      </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
      <div class="item-container">
          <div class="item-top"><span>The Project</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item-bottom-project-content">The Project</div>
          <div class="item-bottom-project">Help</div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="item-container">
          <div class="item-top"><span>Behind the Scenes</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item-bottom-behind-content">Behind the Scenes</div>
          <div class="item-bottom-behind">Take a Peek</div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="item-container">
          <div class="item-top"><span>What's</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item-bottom-batten-content">What's</div>
          <div class="item-bottom-batten">Learn More</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    </a>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="item-container">
          <div class="item-top"><span>About</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item-bottom-about-content">About</div>
          <div class="item-bottom-about">Get Acquainted</div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="item-container">
          <div class="item-top"><span>Sharing is Caring</span>
          </div>
          <div class="item-bottom-sharing-content">Sharing is Caring</div>
          <div class="item-bottom-sharing">Join the Chatter</div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works well but I can't seem to replicate in a jsFiddle? To tidy up the nesting/structural level issues how much work would it be?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of answers about the positioning, so I would like to add another style, a different there and back transition, see the fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/dLz8fL80/3/

Explication:

So we have this transition on `.item-container`

```
.item-container {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 225px;
    line-height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

And this one on the `.item-container:hover`

```
.item-container:hover {
    top: -225px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 200ms;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 200ms;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 200ms;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 200ms;
}
```

When your mouse will go to the `.item-container`, the :hover transition effect will apply, and when your mouse will leave, the other will do the effect.

So I apply a waiting on the `:hover`, that way, you avoid to move everything when flying-by and a slower leaving animation.

Answer (score -1):

Use proper nesting for UL and Li and styling will be easier. Do not use div within list tags
Example :

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">The Song</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="item-bottom-song-content">The Song</li>
        <li class="item-bottom-song">Have a Listen</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Although I agree about your semantic advise for this specific case, it might indeed be better as you propose,  `div` within a `li` is not a bad practice as such, some designs might need it...  That said, it doesn't answer the question at all...

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
nav ul li {
    width: 16.65%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 225px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/2r9t1kbr/4/)

Answer (score -2):

You have the hover effect on the `.item-container` but you should make the hover on the `.item-top` or you make a `<p>` Tag around the text you will hover and make the hover effect on `p:hover`

Comment: The answer does not helps the OP anyway.

Comment: why shouldn't it it helps for sure!

Comment: Kindly first see what the OP asked for. He wants the whole .item-container(parent) div to move up on hovering the text inside(child) it. You could not change parent by hover on a child.